# C Random numbers for ASCII, why is this code wrong?

Tags: c

```
char generateRandom(void)
{
  time_t t;
  srand((unsigned) time(%t));

  char choice = (char) rand() % 5 + 65;

  return choice;
}
```

I'm trying to randomly generate characters from A to G by using rand() function, add 65 to make the range of numbers 65 to 71, and convert it to char value.

When I try to run this though, I get an error saying "expected expression before token".

I'm not very sure what my line of code is doing wrong syntax-wise.

Comment: Post more of the code around this line.

Comment: `expected expression before token".` This error not from this line.error is else where.

Comment: This is literally the only code in the function it is in aside from returning that very value.

Comment: `%` ==>> `&` .....(and that isn't the place to seed your prng anyway, that should be done once per process-run, ideally at the start of `main()` before first-use of `rand()`).

Comment: `srand((unsigned) time(%t));` this line.

Comment: by the way `(char) rand() % 5 + 65;` doesn't give u A ~ G

Comment: the time function returns the current time value if the parameter is null, so the t variable can be eliminated. then the line is srand( time(NULL) );  This will eliminate the invalid syntax your code is currently using.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
srand((unsigned) time(%t));
//                    ^
```

should be:

```
srand((unsigned) time(&t));
//                    ^
```

The `%` operator is a binary one (`a % b`) that tries to find the modulus (the remainder when you divide `a` by `b`). The `&` operator is a unary one (`&a`) that gives you a pointer to the `a` object. It's the latter you need to use here (but see below since you *don't* actually need to use it at all).

You have a few other problems as well, among them:

- You should seed the random number generator *once* (probably in `main()`), not every time you want a random number.
- You can just seed it with `srand (time (0))` since passing a NULL means you don't want to *store* the time. There's no need to create the `t` variable for this case.
- The expression `number % 5` will give you a value from `0` to `4` inclusive. That's only going to deliver `A` through `E`. You should be using `7`.
- Your code will be more readable if you add `'A'` rather than the magic number `65`.
- there's no *need* to cast you result to a character and, in any case, you're only casting the result of `rand()` with the code you have (which, in conjunction with `%`, may result in a negative number in environments where `char` is signed by default). You should include the whole expression in parentheses if you want to cast it but I'd suggest removing the cast altogether.

As an aside, for *full* portability, you shouldn't even assume that the letters are contiguous since the standard only guarantees that for `0-9` and nothing else.

If you're the type to worry about that sort of stuff, you'd be better off using something like:

```
char genRandom (void) {
    return "ABCDEFG"[rand() % 7]; // assume srand already called.
}
```

Comment: He's changing the % to a &, in case you have difficulty noticing.

Comment: Voted up for being the first to point out it's better to use 'A' instead of 65.

Comment: @cwallenpoole, I see no evidence of that. In any case, the code he posted clearly has that problem, amongst the others I've listed.

Comment: Didn't vote up for not noticing the cast. See the answer of @haccks

Comment: Somewhere down the list of what's wrong with that function is that fact that rand()%7 gives you a (slightly) biased random number, and also may give you a not very independent random number if rand() is implemented with an LCG.

Comment: @paxdiablo I was referring to your post. I looked at the original for about 5 minutes before realizing that was the difference.

Comment: Ah, sorry, @cwallenpoole, I thought you were pointing out that _I'd_ missed something, not that you were expanding on my answer. Apologies, and I'll make it (hopefully) clearer.

Comment: @rici, I wasn't going to include every single little thing, just the major ones. Why don't we just assume for now that the generator is actually a white-noise-based, perfectly random one, and that `RAND_MAX` is a multiple of seven :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: Fair enough. Although I think the probability that RAND_MAX is divisible by 7 is equal to the probability that A-G do not have consecutive codes. :) (As far as I know, there is no C implementation for a system whose native character set is Baudot code.)

Answer (score 1):

Change these two lines

```
srand((unsigned) time(%t));
char choice = (char) rand() % 7 + 65;  //It will not give the characters from A to G
```

to

```
srand((unsigned) time(&t));
char choice = (char) (rand() % 7 + 65); // or remove the cast
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it working on gcc  :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
main()
{
   srand(time(NULL));
   char rc=(char)(rand()%7)+65;
   printf("%c",rc);
}
```